# What does Disney consider to be Star Wars canon?

Tags: star-wars, canon, disney

I know the original movies, as well as I think the *Clone Wars* and *Rebels* cartoons were brought forward. I know Disney's movies are canon, and I assume the books being released after Disney purchase are canon as well.

But are all things put out after Disney purchase canon? Like story mode of Battlefront 2?

Curious what gets labeled as canon and what does not, and is there a distinction to know the difference?

Comment: i'm guessing it didn't pull up on my search because of the word Canonicity?  o well, thanks for pointing me to an answer

Comment: Seems likely, search here isn't the best. There is also the tag [tag:canon] that you can use that should help track down questions like this (assuming they are all tagged correctly of course).

Comment: I think [this counts](https://www.dailydot.com/wp-content/uploads/af1/8a/cbbd3afcc97d76cd-725x512.jpg), at least.